# jQuery, Sliding vertical text just goes off the screen without circling back

Tags: jquery

Here's my code so far,

```
  function richardsSuperAmazingVerticalTextScroller(){


        $('#honor-roll ul').animate(
        { 
            top: '-=' + $('#honor-roll ul li:last').height()
        },
        1000,
        'linear',
        function(){
            var offset = $('#honor-roll ul li:last').offset().top;                
            console.log(offset);
            if( offset <= 640){
                 $('#honor-roll ul li').css("margin", 0);
                 $('#honor-roll ul li:last').after($('#honor-roll ul li:first').detach());
            }
        }
    );
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval('richardsSuperAmazingVerticalTextScroller()',1000)
    });
```

on jsFiddle it works perfectly, but in this version it fails, http://barkins.com/test.html

Here is the same code on Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/qmFD3/6/

Can anyone spot the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's not the same code. In particular, your jsFiddle has

```
if( offset <= 640){
    $('#honor-roll ul').css("top", 0);
    $('#honor-roll ul li:last').after($('#honor-roll ul li:first').detach());
}
```

While the code on your site has

```
if( offset <= 640){
    $('#honor-roll ul li').css("margin", 0);
    $('#honor-roll ul li:last').after($('#honor-roll ul li:first').detach());
}
```

Changing that fixes the problem.

As a side note, you shouldn't be using a string in your `setTimeout`. You can change it to just:

```
setInterval(richardsSuperAmazingVerticalTextScroller,1000)
```

Comment: I made the updates to the website, however still having the same problem. Here's the updated version, http://barkins.com/test.html

Comment: You're using different versions of jQuery. Why aren't you using 1.9.1?

Comment: Bingo! Sadly, the CMS I'm inserting the code into has the older version of jQuery built into it. I will need to try inserting the newer version as well and see if it works while pointing to both version of jQuery. Thank you!

Comment: Debugging. It's a useful way to figure out what's going wrong with your code. Read up on Chrome (or Firebug) development tools.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
$('#honor-roll ul li').css("top", 0);
```

to:

```
$('#honor-roll ul').css("top", 0); // Note the li
```

as well as wrap all your jQuery code inside `$(document).ready(function() { });`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#honor-roll ul').css({display:"none"});
    $('#honor-roll ul').fadeIn('slow');
    setInterval(richardsSuperAmazingVerticalTextScroller,1000)
});
```

---

Edit:

I think I know the reason why your code doesn't work, it's because of your jQuery version

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qmFD3/7/)** that has exactly the same problem as your site

So you just need to use another jQuery version to your site and it should work.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, made those changes, but still having the issue, http://barkins.com/test.html

Comment: @Richard Your css in the fiddle and your site is not the same as well as your jQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it´s all about putting the

```
 <script>
```

inside the body-element

Comment: It's not. That doesn't make a difference.